# Detail from multires and mirror object

Tags: mirror, multiresolution

I have a mirrored object with a multires modifier. When i apply the mirror modifier in a lower Level the higher multires Level are lost when i apply it in a higher Level the mirror is not closing all the gabs in the middle... I checked it in edit mode everything is in the middle but still not working..(increasing the merge Limit will also not help because the mesh is not even)I also tried baking a displacment map which works kinda well but one part was not good and i had to exclude it with weight paint but then it is just at Level one and Looks ugle.. also the seam is bad.. hope someone can help?[image]

Comment: If i understood u mean the center line with the mirror.If so change the order mirror on the top and rest the modifier below the mirror

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but its not possible to move it on top because it require original data.. i could apply it and then mirror it.. will try that thanks!

Comment: That's why it's better to apply Mirror before sculpting (Sculpt has its own way for mirrorring). Remove Mirror and try using Symetrize in Edit or Sculpt mode instead. Note that if not all vertices are on the mirror plane (center of the mesh) Symmetrize will fail as well on that part but you won't left without sculpted data.

Comment: yes did that.. but forgot the toungue of the dino and edit it later on.. to even it out i deleted one have and mirrored it.. when i apply the multires on level one i lose the detail level above..(verts cout is incresing but detail is missing) when i apply it at a higher level the centerline is not corretly closing (i checked in edit mode the center line.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

Add -> Mesh -> Plane

Select the Multires mesh and in the Mirror tab -> Mirror Object-> Plane

Select the plane and adjust the center part moving the plane in x axis in my condition

[image]

Comment: its weird.. the center line is not even but i checked it in edit mode to align them in center.. when i try this method there are overlapping in some points and some are not even closed.. why is clipping here not working?